# How to get the global width of a column-width layout for a random text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="multiColumn">a random and long text</div>

#multiColumn {
  height: 320px;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

With a random text, how do I get the total width of a multi-column layout?

--

I think I found a solution. However it's not the most elegant...

```
#multiColumn {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
}

.columns {
  height: 320px;
  -webkit-column-width: 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}
```

js:

```
var columns_height = 320,
    columns_width = 0,
    column_width = 200,
    column_gap = 20;

nb_columns = Math.ceil($('#multiColumn').height() / columns_height);
columns_width = nb_columns * column_width + (nb_columns-1) * column_gap;

$('#multiColumn').css('width', columns_width + 'px').addClass('columns');
```

Comment: There is a very nice solution for a similar case which, very probably, you could develop on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109076/jquery-function-trouble

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, same way as a regular div:

```
var r_text = new Array ();
r_text[0] = "All the leaves are brown";
r_text[1] = "And the sky is grey";
r_text[2] = "I've been for a walk";
r_text[3] = "On a winter's day";
r_text[4] = "I'd be safe and warm";
r_text[5] = "If I was in L.A.";
r_text[6] = "California dreaming, On such a winter's day";

for (var i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    var j = Math.floor(7*Math.random())
    $('#multiColumn').append(r_text[j]+'');
}

alert($('#multiColumn').width());       <== 596
alert($('#multiColumn').innerWidth());  <== 596
alert($('#multiColumn').outerWidth());  <== 596
```

I, then, changed the css to overflow:scroll. SAME RESULT! Therefore, it has to do with the actual screen area used by the div; not necessarily by the sum of the columns width inside the div.

However though, you could have more management if you could manage to make those inside columns, for example, divs or spans. Maybe there is a innerColumnSumm of some kind that I am not aware of.

Comment: Well yes, the DIV has by default the property display sets to block. I'd hope there was a value for the display property which limits the width to the columns like that http://i.imgur.com/Yqcm8.png.